# Laravel Pivot table with two relationships to the same model not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table

I'm running a Laravel 7 application and I have 2 models in relation to each other.  A `User` model and a `Playlist`.

```
....
App\Playlist

public function user()
{
     return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
....
```

Which is working properly and of course my `Playlist` migration has a foreign key on `user_id`

Now, I'm trying to create a scenario where there's a pivot table that allows other users to be 'invited' to a playlist.  In this scenario, I want to be able to access all of the playlists which a user has been 'invited' and on a playlist, I want to be able to see all of the users that have been invited to the playlist.

I created a pivot table using standard Laravel best practices

```
class CreatePlaylistUserTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('playlist_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('playlist_id');
            $table->foreign('playlist_id')->references('id')->on('playlists')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->unique(['playlist_id', 'user_id']);

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('playlist_user');
    }
}
```

On my User's model I have a `belongsToMany` relationship

```
App\User

    /**
     * The Playlists associated with the user.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function playlists()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Playlist::class);
    }

    /**
     * The Playlists that this user has been invited to.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsMany
     */
    public function invites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Playlist::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
```

and on my Playlist model I have

```
App\Playlist

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function invites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
```

After attaching `users` to `playlists` (`$playlist->invites()->attach($user)`) in my test's I'm able to see all of the playlists for my user (`$user->invites`) but when I go to my playlist to see all the users (`$playlist->invites`) I see an empty collection even though the record exists in my DB

I'm also checking to see if a record exists by doing something like

```
App\User

public function isInvitedToPlaylist($playlist) {
    return $this->invites()->where('playlist_id', $playlist->id)->exists();
}
```

But I keep getting an ambiguous column name : user_id error

```
lluminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 ambiguous column name: user_id (SQL: select exists(select * from "playlists" inner join "playlist_user" on "playlists"."id" = "playlist_user"."playlist_id" where "playlist_user"."user_id" = 3 and "playlist_id" = 1 and "user_id" = 1) as "exists")
```

In my head, I'm querying the "playlistUser list (ie. user_id = 3)" but it's also adding in "user_id = 1" which is the User id of the 'owner' for the playlist

---

Does anyone have experiencing setting up a `belongsToMany` relationship on a model that has 2 relationships to the same model?

Any advice would be appreciated!  I think I've done as much searching and testing as I can!

Thanks!

Comment: Something else I found really odd was:
```
public test_function a_user_can_have_invites()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();
    //$this->assertCount(0, $user->invites);  <--- FAILS
    $playlist = factory(Playlist::class)->create();

    $playlist->invites()->attach($user);

    $this->assertCount(1, $playlist->invites);
    $this->assertCount(1, $user->invites);
}
```
If I check for an empty collection it causes the lower assertion to fail.. If I comment it out, it works !?!?!  WAHH!??!

Answer (score 0):

You are facing the error because you have `user_id` column in both `playlists` and `playlist_user` tables, so you have to mention from which table to select that column, for example `where('playlists.user_id', $id)`

I think adding custom select will help:

```
// Playlist model
public function invites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)
                ->select([
                    'playlist.id',
                    'playlist.user_id',
                     ...
                    'playlist_user.id',
                    'playlist_user.user_id',
                    'playlist_user.playlist_id',
                     ...
                    'users.id',
                    'users.other_column'
                ])
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback but I don't believe this is the case.

In theory, I'm already INSIDE a user model so shouldn't ```$this->instances``` already be scoped to that user?

When I'm doing my ```where``` condition, it's based upon the Playlist ID, not the user id

But I also modified my where to include ```return $this->invites()->where(['playlist_id' => $playlist_id, 'playlist_user.user_id' => $this->id])->exists();``` but the user_id came up again

For some reason Laravel is tacking on the user_id scope on Playlist for the OWNER, not the pivot table

Comment: I've edited the answer please check it. I believe `invites()` method in `Playlist` model is causing the error. Try to fix it like shown in example